# WPF multiple views

Tags: wpf, controls, regions

I have a small WPF application which has multiple controls. I want to change the displayed control when click on a button. A solution is to play with ***Visibility*** property of the controls. Do other ways exist?

Comment: You could set the `Content` property of any `ContentControl` in your application.

Comment: Have look at the [Control templates](http://www.wpftutorial.net/templates.html). HTH

Comment: If you're using a ToggleButton, then you could bind the Visibility of the control to the IsChecked property. That could be fun.